# Using Yowsup or WhatsAPI to send messages to Whatsapp groups

Tags: backend, message, whatsapp

I'm trying to send a message to a group from my application/ server. I want to use Yowsup or WhatsAPI. Which is better? How should I go about it?

This is what I've found for Yowsup: http://openwhatsapp.org/develop/ and https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup

This is what I've found for WhatsAPI: https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI

Also, I'm building a web application, not a native one. Is this a problem?

Comment: No luck, both api are down...i tried to make whatsapi run yesterday with no luck.

Comment: There is no better one. They both implement the FunXMPP protocol. Consider node-whatsapi also.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the language of programming you are Good at What API uses PHP. use the update library here https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/tree/master

The best way to start is by downloading the examples and reading the wiki before getting started the examples are fully functional.

Yowsup is python based library and I have not had a look at it :( on any-day I would go for What API, and YES you can integrate it with your php web scripts.

Hope this helped